# Nested Functions and Blowing away Global Variable

Tags: javascript

There's something I need to understand and I have [done up a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q4xnxuQlwJRi1WX05mBN) to help convey my question.

JavaScript:

```
// "person" written as a plain object
var person = {
    showName: function () { return this.name; },
    setName: function (newName) { this.name = newName; }
};

//  room is class where nested function is a lambda
var room1 = {
    capacity: 10,
    exits: 2,
    count: 0,
    person: 'this property is a String, not an Object',
    addPerson: function (name) {
        this.count += 1;
        this.person = name;
        var nestedFunction = function (name) {
            this.person = name + ' name has been blown away';
        }(name);
    }
};

//  room is class where nested function is a method
var room2 = {
    capacity: 10,
    exits: 2,
    count: 0,
    person: 'this property is a String, not an Object',
    addPerson: function (name) {
        this.count += 1;
        this.person = name;
        function nestedFunction(name) {
            this.person = name + ' name has been blown away';
        }(name);
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<input id="PersonObjectButton" type="submit" value="Click Me First to See Person showName Method Called"
           onclick="person.setName('Dave');alert(person.showName());" /> <br /> 
<input id="PersonObjectButtonAwry" type="submit" value="Click Me To Blow Away Global Variable" 
           onclick="room1.addPerson('Alan');alert(person);" /> <br />              
<input id="PersonObjectButtonFine" type="submit" value="Click Me to See Person showName Method Called" 
           onclick="room2.addPerson('Alan');alert(person.showName());" /> <br />
```

If you run that plunk and hit the top button, it displays the name "Steve". Nothing hard there. When you click the button below that, it displays the text "Alan is now here. Other name has been blown away." I think I understand that. Basically, the nestedFunction in **room1** is a function and NOT method. Because it is not a method with is a member of any object, it is in the Global namespace and it blows away the *person* variable (and thus, the *this* keyword does not hold a reference to the **room1** object).

It is the 3rd button which I do not quite follow. If you refresh the page and click the 3rd button, you'll see that the variable does not blow away the *person* variable in the Global namespace. In that case, the *this* keyword does hold a reference to the **room1** object.

My question is, what is it about the *named function*, which is not created as a function expression, that makes it a member of the **room2** object, despite being nested? Or even just why doesn't it blow away the global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `room1` you have a function expression which gets immediately executed (also called [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)). You are right that `this` refers to the global object. Thus

```
var nestedFunction = function (name) {
    this.person = name + ' name has been blown away';
}(name);
```

is equivalent to

```
window.person = name + ' name has been blown away';
```

In the second case you use a function *declaration*. Even though it *looks* like it, the function is **not** executed. The code is actually interpreted as *two* statements:

```
function nestedFunction(name) {
    this.person = name + ' name has been blown away';
} // end of function declaration
(name); // an expression statement which doesn't do anything
```

It's the same as

```
function nestedFunction(name) {
    this.person = name + ' name has been blown away';
}
name;
```

or just

```
function nestedFunction(name) {
    this.person = name + ' name has been blown away';
}
```

---

> My question is, what is it about the named function, which is not created as a function expression, that makes it a member of the `room2` object, despite being nested?

Nothing, it does **not** become a property value of `room2`.

> Or even just why doesn't it blow away the global variable?

Because the function is never executed. If you put `nestedFunction();` after the declaration, it behaves exactly like in `room1`.

Comment: Ahhh. That makes sense. Thanks for the well-explained answer.

Comment: Interesting to see what happens when I surround the declared function "nestedFunction" in brackets. It interprets it all as 1 statement, self-invokes the function and blows the Global variable away.

Comment: Yes, because as the grouping operator (`(...)`) can only contain expressions, the function definition is interpreted as (named) function *expression*, just like in the first example.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. So many little nuances in that wonderful language. I love it!

Answer (score 3):

This is because the nestedFunction definition and `(name)` in room2 are two separate statements.

```
var nestedFunction = function (name) {
    this.person = name + ' name has been blown away';
}(name);
```

This code will create a function, call it with the name variable and then assign the return value to `nestedFunction`.

```
function nestedFunction(name) {
    this.person = name + ' name has been blown away';
}(name);
```

This code on the other hand creates a named function. The return value of that operation is always undefined, so you can't immediately invoke the function. Instead it will be treated as two separate statements:

```
function nestedFunction(name) {
    this.person = name + ' name has been blown away';
};(name);
```

It creates a function and then evaluates the variable!

To demonstrate in the Javascript console:

```
function nestedFunction(name) {
     console.log("called")
}("example")
// "example"
```

Comment: This is actually not a case of automatic semicolon insertion. There is never a semicolon after a function declaration, hence the parser would not insert one there. More info: http://es5.github.io/#x7.9.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh, thanks for pointing that out. So the reason it doesn't try to call undefined as a function is because the statement is terminated without the need for a semicolon?